# String to text output

Tags: java, if-statement

This may seem like a stupid question. How do I make this if statement print?

```
 private void btnCheckMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        String height;
        height = heightCm.getText();
        if ((height >=122) && (height <=188)){
            outputCheck.setText("WORKING...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert height to integer. `int height = Integer.parseInt(heightCm.getText());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert height to integer. Then you will be able to compare it in your if statement.

```
int height = Integer.parseInt(heightCm.getText());
```